# Can we make Mirror Maker 2 (MM2) selectively replicate data from source to target?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am running a dedicated MM2 cluster in each of my 4 DataCenters(DC). All of them are designed to work in Active/Active mode. This means that either of the 4 DCs should be able to replicate data to one another. Due to this setup, I am running into a scenario where data entering into a topic 'A' in a certain DC could have been produced in the same DC or could be a replicated copy from another DC. I need to be able to identify this and either allow this data to be replicated ahead to other DCs or stop it. My idea is to have the producer in the original DC add an origin header in each record, which I can then track to restrict data from being replicated more than once along the chain of replication flows.

This requires me to gain control over what records get written into the target cluster. I have tried the below approaches but none work.

1. Extend the MirrorSourceConnector and supply it as connector.class in the connect-mirror-maker.properties. However, this approaches causes MM2 to replicate the messages 3X times since MM2 uses my custom connector class for configuring the MirrorHeartbeatConnector and the MirrorCheckpointConnector as well, effectively creating 3 source connectors somehow.

`connector.class=com.visa.CustomMirrorSourceConnector`

2. Define a custom transform filter to read the record header and filter unwanted records. Below is just a sample transform usage to see if MM2 is able to honor it. I don't intend to really use this one.

```
transforms=InsertSource1
transforms.InsertSource1.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
transforms.InsertSource1.static.field=test_inser
transforms.InsertSource1.static.value=test_value
```

However, I get the below error.

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Missing required configuration "transforms.InsertSource1.type" which has no default value.
Invalid value null for configuration transforms.InsertSource1.type: Not a Transformation
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint /connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate
```

It seems to me that both the above approaches are only possible when running a standalone MirrorMaker connector.

Is there any way to have control over what records get replicated when running a dedicated MM2 cluster?

below is how my Active/Active replication is setup.

```
DC1 topic.dc1 (local) topic.dc2 (remote)   
DC2 topic.dc1 (remote) topic.dc2 (local)
```

Producer in DC1 writes data (with origin header dc1) to topic.dc1 which then gets replicated to topic.dc1 (remote). Another Consumer-Producer set will read data from topic.dc1 (remote) and write it to topic.dc2 (local) for other local consumers like elastic search, etc Similarly, the data from topic.dc2 will be replicate to topic.dc2 (remote). This is how we are establishing Active-Active replication.

This all works fine but lets say we have DC3 as well.

```
DC3 topic.dc1 (remote) topic.dc2 (remote) topic.dc3 (local).
```

Data from `topic.dc2 (local)` could make its way to DC3 and the same data could make its way from `topic.dc1 (local)` as well. We want to stop one of these replications and we intend to do this by using the origin header so that we prevent cycles. So we indeed need the filter predicate but unfortunately, I don't see it available in this standalone MM2 mode

Comment: To clarify, you're not renaming the destination topics and having the consumers read from pattern like `topic-name(-DC[1-4])?`? Also, this transform isn't adding a header, it'd be directly modifying the record value, potentially overriding the static field, if it existed. Plus, if each of your producer applications already know where they are deployed to, you could just update them all to add such origin metadata, via a shared common library across the org. Then, you can chose to drop any event without those fields before they actually reach the broker

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for the reply. Sorry if I didn't clarify in my original post (I have now) but the filter I have used is just a sample to check if MM2 works with it. It's not intended to add the origin header but for MM2 to filter the events. I am looking to solve your last part of the comment. "Then, you can chose to drop any event without those fields before they actually reach the broker" How should I make MM2 drop the events while it tries tor replicate from source to destination broker?

Comment: MM2 wouldn't. I'm saying your producer clients would all need modified to inject records with their known source datacenter information. Then, you don't need insert transforms, and you can use `Filter / Predicate` ones instead to drop certain messages.

Comment: In any case, Transforms do work with MM2, but I've only tested with `connect-distributed` mode, not standalone or `connect-mirror-maker` script

Comment: My only experience with this is having a commonly named topic, not a datacenter topic suffix. For example, we used `.global`, as a "mirrored, write-only, fan-in" topic that contained data from all remote data centers, and these topics were never forwarded elsewhere from that "destination cluster", so there was no duplication. The question then becomes - do your consumers actually care which datacenter the data comes from? Note: [Cycle detection](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382:+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-Cycledetection) is a documented feature

Comment: Also, `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter` is definitely available on the classpath of Kafka Connect, but it doesn't work on record header values.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, not sure if you saw my architecture design. Stack Overflow seemed to delete my comment explaining that.

Anyways, MM2 documented Cycle detection is limited to topic names and not data so unfortunately it doesn't help me too much.

Comment: I edited the question so that others may see it without scrolling in the comments. Regarding the topic names, you can use `RegexRouter` transform to modify topic names in Connect framework. Still - this requires your classpath to be correct to load the built-in transforms. Otherwise, like I said, the `Filter` transform class should work too, and `TopicNameMatches` predicate can be used without touching record values/headers.